# Decompose native gates using Qiskit framework

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I've read the papers about quantum hardware. These papers [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11349) [[2]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/938431) mention that native gates of IBM quantum computer are $R_x(\pi/2), R_z(\lambda)\space and \space CR \space (Cross Resonance)$

My questions are:

1. Getting native gates in qikit, we use `transpile()`. So, does "rx" does it equal to $R_x(\pi/2)$?
2. How to decompose CX to CR gates from that `transpile()`?
3. For Ion trapped native qubits, there is $Rxy(\theta,\phi)$, so does it equal to "rx" and "ry" in `transpile()` ?

Code example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rx', 'ry', 'cx'])
print(qc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the native gates on IBM Quantum computers, you can see for example on ibmq_bogota [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems&system=ibmq_bogota) that the basis gates are **CX, ID, RZ, SX, X** :

- **CX** is the usual 2-qubits CNOT gate;
- **ID** is the single qubit identity gate;
- **X** is the single qubit NOT gate and **SX** is its square root;
- **RZ** is the single qubit rotation about the Z-axis, see [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZGate.html?highlight=rzgate#qiskit.circuit.library.RZGate) its definition, and it is the single parameterised gate of the basis gates set so technically it will be **$RZ(\lambda)$** but we'll denote it via **RZ** by misuse of language since it's clear it is **$RZ(\lambda)$**.

To sum up you'll have to pass `basis_gates=['cx', 'id', 'rz', 'x', 'sx']` to the transpiler to use basis gates of ibm machines.

Now about $R_{X,Y}$ I can't seem to find it on qiskit but if its definition is similar to [$R_{Z,X}$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZXGate.html) then by using this [kind of tools](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.evolutions.html?highlight=exp_i) you can implement it easily I think.

Finally, if you wish to play more with hardware, then you might be interested in qiskit pulse, see some tutos [in the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/index.html) or [the textbook](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware-pulses/calibrating-qubits-using-qiskit-pulse).